# How to display the data by SQL Join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

hello everyone i want to ask for help for my case.

First table data mainproduct

```
id  | barcode       | product_name         | unit_kg |
====+===============+======================+=========+===
1   | 8995157800257 | Pandan Wangi CF 5kg  | 5       |
2   | 8995157800264 | Pandan Wangi CF 10kg | 10      |
3   | 8995157800271 | Pandan Wangi CF 20kg | 20      |
4   | 8995157800288 | Rojolele CF 5kg      | 5       |
5   | 8995157800301 | Rojolele CF 20kg     | 20      |
6   | 8995157800318 | SR CF 5kg            | 5       |
7   | 8995157800325 | SR CF 10kg           | 10      |
8   | 8995157800332 | SR CF 20kg           | 20      |
```

Second table data detail_order

```
id  | barcode       | product_name         | pcs_order | date_order |
====+===============+======================+=========+==============+==
1   | 8995157800257 | Pandan Wangi CF 5kg  | 5         | 2018-01-01
2   | 8995157800257 | Pandan Wangi CF 5kg  | 2         | 2018-01-05
3   | 8995157800257 | Pandan Wangi CF 5kg  | 6         | 2018-02-01
4   | 8995157800264 | Pandan Wangi CF 10kg | 4         | 2018-02-02
5   | 8995157800264 | Pandan Wangi CF 10kg | 9         | 2018-02-03
6   | 8995157800271 | Pandan Wangi CF 20kg | 1         | 2018-02-04
7   | 8995157800271 | Pandan Wangi CF 20kg | 2         | 2018-02-05
8   | 8995157800271 | Pandan Wangi CF 20kg | 1         | 2018-02-10
9   | 8995157800288 | Rojolele CF 5kg      | 5         | 2018-02-15
10  | 8995157800288 | Rojolele CF 5kg      | 3         | 2018-02-16
11  | 8995157800318 | SR CF 5kg            | 8         | 2018-02-20
12  | 8995157800318 | SR CF 5kg            | 2         | 2018-02-25
13  | 8995157800325 | SR CF 10kg           | 10        | 2018-02-28
14  | 8995157800325 | SR CF 10kg           | 5         | 2018-03-01
```

I want to retrieve the turnover data from the detail_order table with its product barcode, but even though the product data in the mainproduct table is not in the detail_order table, I want to keep it displayed with later total_order 0 if it is not in the detail_order table. Less than as below:

```
id_mainproduct  | barcode       | product_name         | total_order_pcs    |
================+===============+======================+====================+===
1               | 8995157800257 | Pandan Wangi CF 5kg  | 6                  |
2               | 8995157800264 | Pandan Wangi CF 10kg | 13                 |
3               | 8995157800271 | Pandan Wangi CF 20kg | 4                  |
4               | 8995157800288 | Rojolele CF 5kg      | 8                  |
5               | 8995157800301 | Rojolele CF 20kg     | 0                  |
6               | 8995157800318 | SR CF 5kg            | 10                 |
7               | 8995157800325 | SR CF 10kg           | 10                 |
8               | 8995157800332 | SR CF 20kg           | 0                  |
```

actually I can connect the two tables, but in the data section in mainproduct that does not have data in detail_order, I can not display it, please help me.

my code:

```
SELECT mainproduct.id,
       mainproduct.barcode,
       mainproduct.product_name,
       SUM(R.pcs_order) as total_order
FROM
(
  SELECT barcode, pcs_order, date_order
  FROM detail_order
) AS R
LEFT JOIN mainproduct ON mainproduct.barcode = R.barcode
WHERE r.date_order BETWEEN '2018-02-01' AND '2018-02-28' GROUP BY mainproduct.id
ORDER BY mainproduct.id ASC
```

Comment: It looks like you need a left join rather than a join.

Comment: can you help me for the sql code?

Comment: Please add the code you have to the question.

Comment: @P.Salmon, a left join is a join.

Comment: @jarlh that's not helpful.

Comment: If you want to be helpful you should say "_It looks like you need a left join rather than an inner join_".

Comment: you can see my code

Comment: I'd consider "main table left join detail".

Comment: Re-order your joins. You have `DETAIL left join MAIN` but you want `MAIN left join DETAIL`

Comment: I have fixed my question, there is zero data unavailable because there is a date criteria in the detail_order table from the beginning and end of the date required to display.

Comment: Why are you storing product name in the detail_order table? Why has no one thought to question this already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of your comments, you still have the join in the wrong order.

`a LEFT JOIN b` means to keep every record that appears in `a`, even if there is no corresponding row in `b`.

If you want the sales volume of ***every*** product, even when there are no sales records for a product *(showing a zero)*, you need `products LEFT JOIN sales`.

If you only want to count sales during a specific window of time, filter the sales *Before* the join *(sub, in your sub-query)*.

```
SELECT
   mainproduct.id,
   mainproduct.barcode,
   mainproduct.product_name,
   COALESCE(SUM(R.pcs_order), 0)    AS total_order
FROM
   mainproduct
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT barcode, pcs_order, date_order
    FROM detail_order
   WHERE date_order BETWEEN '2018-02-01' AND '2018-02-28'
)
   AS R
      ON mainproduct.barcode = R.barcode
GROUP BY
   mainproduct.id
ORDER BY
   mainproduct.id ASC
```

Comment: forgive me for my mistake, I am very confused in this case about how the code should I make to succeed with hope.

the code you gave was successful with hope, thanks for your help and learning, my case is now solved. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You need to join your tables and do aggregation

```
select p.barcode,p.product_name, coalesce(sum(d.pcs_order),0)
from mainproduct p
left join detail_order d on p.barcode = d.barcode
group by p.barcode, p.product_name
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fbea5e/3)

Comment: Might be worth commenting to the OP why this is different from their code.  *(You have the tables in the correct order, the OP had them joined in the wrong order...)*

Comment: I have fixed my question, there is zero data unavailable because there is a date criteria in the detail_order table from the beginning and end of the date required to display.

Comment: @MatBailie There was no attempt posted by OP while i was posting it as an answer, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple queries for the same problem. You can use this.

```
select p.barcode,p.product_name, coalesce(d.pcs_order, 0)
from (select barcode, sum(pcs_order) pcs_order from detail_order group by barcode) as d
right join mainproduct p on p.barcode = d.barcode
```